# system.collections.generic.list to system.collections.generic.ienumerable

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have a method where list cannot convert to ienumerable. How do i cast???

```
 public ActionResult Attending()
 {
    var userId = User.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;
    var gigs = _context.Attendances.Include(a => a.Gig.Artist).Include(a => a.Gig.Genre).Where(a => a.AttendeeId == userId).ToList();
    var viewModel = new GigsViewModel()
    {
       UpcomingGigs = gigs,
       ShowActions = User.Identity.IsAuthenticated,
       Heading = "Gigs I'm Attending"
       };
       return View("Gigs", viewModel);
    }
```

Here is my ViewModel:

```
public class GigsViewModel
{
   public IEnumerable<Gig> UpcomingGigs { get; set; }
   public bool ShowActions { get; set; }
   public string Heading { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also first fetch all attendees, and select the gigs.

```
IEnumerable<Gig> gigs = _context.Attendances.Where(a => a.AttendeeId == userId).Select(a => a.Gig).ToList();
```

Be aware if there can be multiple similar gigs, then perhaps you need only distinct set of gigs using Distinct:

```
IEnumerable<Gig> gigs = _context.Attendances.Where(a => a.AttendeeId == userId).Select(a => a.Gig).Distinct().ToList();
```

See more at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803(v=vs.110).aspx

Edited: edited the old suggestion, Distinct and Select added.

Comment: I tried, now it shows cannot implicitly convert IQueryable to IEnumerable

Answer (score 0):

Try using below code, AsEnumerable() will do your work

```
var gigs = _context.Attendances.Where(a => a.AttendeeId == userId).select(a=> 
new Gig()
 {
   property = a.property //assuming property, you can repeat the same for other properties of Gig
 }).AsEnumerable();
```

The result of a Linq database query is typically IQueryable which is derived from IEnumerable, IQueryable, and IEnumerable.

In your case,it's linq database query so you need to call AsEnumerable();

Comment: cannot implicitly convert IEnumerable <Gighub.Model.Attendance> to IEnumerable<Gighub.Model.Gig> an explicit conversion exists

Comment: @SaeefAl-Deen you need to perform projection using select as the source type (Attendance) and destination type (Gig) are different. Please see updated answer